# Questins on Formulae for Eigenvalues & Eigenvectors of any 2 by 2 Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A =  \begin{bmatrix}
>     a & b \\
>     c & d \\ 
>     \end{bmatrix}$. Then $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0 \implies \lambda_{\pm}  \frac{\text{Trace} \pm \sqrt{\text{Trace}^2 - 4\det}}{2} = \frac{(a + d) \pm \sqrt{(a - d)^2 + 4bc}}{2}$.
>   **Case 1:** If $c \neq 0$, then $\mathbf{v_1} =\begin{bmatrix}
>     \lambda_+ - d \\ c
>     \end{bmatrix}^T $ and $\mathbf{v_2} = \begin{bmatrix}
>     \lambda_- - d \\ c
>     \end{bmatrix}^T $
>   **Case 2:** If $b \neq 0$, then $\mathbf{v_1} = \begin{bmatrix}
>     b \\ \lambda_+ - a 
>     \end{bmatrix} $ and $\mathbf{v_2} = \begin{bmatrix}
>     b \\ \lambda_{-} - a 
>     \end{bmatrix} $
>   **Case 3:** If $b = c = 0$, then $\mathbf{v_1 = e_1}^T$ and $\mathbf{v_2 = e_2}^T $

$\Large{{2.}}$ After calculating the eigenvalues, how would you analyse $(A - \lambda I)\mathbf{x}  = \mathbf{0} $ in general?
Then how and why would you determine to take cases?

$\Large{{3.}}$ How and why only $3$ cases? 
What about the case $a, b, c, d \neq 0$? Then $(A - \lambda I)\mathbf{x}  = \mathbf{0} $
$\implies \left[
      \begin{array}{cc|c}
        a-\lambda & b & 0 \\
    c & d-\lambda & 0\\
      \end{array}
    \right]$. $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0 \iff$ $A$ singular $\iff$ Rows lin-dependent. Thus, for each $\lambda$,
$\mathbf{v} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \color{#FF4F00}{\LARGE{-}}\text{ entry in 2nd column of either row } \\ \text{ entry in first column of either row }
    \end{bmatrix} : \begin{bmatrix}
    \color{#FF4F00}{-}(d - \lambda) \\ c
    \end{bmatrix} $ or $\begin{bmatrix}
    \color{#FF4F00}{-}b \\ a - \lambda
    \end{bmatrix} $.
Moreover, what about the case where $b = 0$ ? Then $a - \lambda$ is a pivot so $rank(A - \lambda I) = 1 \text{ or } 2$?

Comment: For example, **Case 1** says that $ c \ne 0$, but it handles all other cases, including $b=0$. Substitute $b=0$ in the general formula you found and see that it works. So, this is possible in the $2x2$ case, but not possible for anything larger. For the $2x2$, you can analyze all of the permutations and soon realize that it can be compactly written into three cases. Regards

Comment: @LePressentiment : do you really want to memorize "the general formula"  (I looked at the link and there are actually at least 4 formulas)?  I don't, and I never will.  If you know the procedure for a 2-by-2 matrix, you can handle larger matrices.  I honestly see no point in memorizing these formulas unless you have some bizarre job that requires you to compute many eigenpairs of 2-by-2 matrices by hand every day.  Understanding the basic procedure (solving the characteristic polynomial and then finding the nullspaces of the $A-\lambda I$'s) does not require worrying about how many cases...

Comment: ...there are or knowing what to do in advance for each case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No, I don't want to memorise. For want of avoiding this and assimilating it instead, are there any ways to intuit or naturalise the general formulae ? I asked because in Strang, there are $\ge 10 $ exercises requiring the computation of the $\det$ of $2$ by $2$ matrices.

Comment: @LePressentiment : since there are so many cases, I don't really think there is an intuitive way to interpret the formulas.  One useful trick is to note that the trace of a matrix is the sum of the eigenvalues and the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues.  I often use this trick to _construct_ matrices whose eigenvalues are predetermined numbers.  You can use this trick to confirm that the eigenvalues you computed are correct.  This says nothing about the eigen_vectors_, of course.

Comment: @LePressentiment : concerning the Strang book, you should be aware that people have strong opinions about the book, pro and con.  I dislike the book very much.  If you look at the customer reviews of the book at amazon.com, there are many that are positive and many that are negative, and the some of the negative reviews describe well what is wrong with the book.  I am not familiar with a lot of alternative texts, but I much prefer Lay's, though I think it has many flaws.  Strang may be a great mathematician, but I don't want you to have the impression that everyone loves his book, ...

Comment: ...and that simply is not the case.

Comment: @StefanSmith: Thank you very much for your candidness. I don't love the book either; majorly more examples and detail on steps would help. I haven't found a better alternative for intuition though. I'm also using David Poole's *Linear Algebra* but it feels less intuitive.

Comment: I just remember that the characteristic polynomial of a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ is $\lambda^2 - \text{trace}(A)\lambda + \det(A)$.  Apart from that, this method is merely spelling out the standard method in detail.

Comment: @LePressentiment is the answer I provided helpful?

Comment: @user139388: +1. Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's compute the eigenvalues of $A_{2\times 2}$ in the general case: the characteristic polynomial is
$$
  f_A(\lambda)
= \det\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
  \lambda - a & -b \\
  -c          & \lambda - d
  \end{array}
  \right]
%= (\lambda - a)(\lambda - d) - bc
= \lambda^2 -(a+d)\lambda +ad- bc,
$$
which has roots
$$
  \lambda
= \frac{a+d \pm \sqrt{(a  +d)^2 - 4(ad-bc)}}{2}
= \frac{a+d \pm \sqrt{(a-d)^2 \color{red} + 4bc}}{2}.
$$

For the second question, I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, but after finding an eigenvalue $\lambda$ one generally analyzes $(A - \lambda I) {\bf x} = {\bf 0}$ in order to find elements of the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$, and this is done by Gaussian elimination. Illustrating with the matrix $A$ given above,
$$
     [A - \lambda I]
=    \left[
     \begin{array}{cc}
     -1 & 1/2 \\
     -2 & 1 \\
     \end{array}
     \right]
\sim \left[
     \begin{array}{cc}
     1 & -1/2 \\
     0 &  0 \\
     \end{array}
     \right];
$$
the first row corresponds to the equation $x_1-\frac{1}{2}x_2=0$, and so the eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda=2$ are of the form ${\bf x} = t[1, 2]^\top$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$. This process generalizes to any finite dimensional matrix, and your solution set may contain more basic solutions (i.e. your eigenspace may be of higher dimension than $1$, as happened here). I hope this answers your second question.

I'm a little confused about the formulae given for the eigenvectors in your post, because I can't tell if you mean for the vectors in case 1 to be *left* eigenvectors or not (you superscripted them with ${}^T$). To explain why the cases don't seem to exhaust all possibilities, think along these lines: either both $c$ and $b$ are equal to $0$ (case 3), or at least one of the is not (cases 1 and 2 together).
Lets try to find a general formula for the (right) eigenvectors, using the evalues we found above: note that in case 3
$$
  [A - \lambda I]
= \left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
  a - \lambda & 0 \\
  0           & d - \lambda \\
  \end{array}
  \right];
$$
now, since you know that $A - \lambda_1 I$ is not invertible, it must be that at least one of these rows is a zero row. If it is the second row then ${\bf e}_1$ is a solution (and hence an evector for $\lambda$), if it is the first row then ${\bf e}_2$ is the solution and evector. If both rows are zero ($\lambda$ was a double root of $f_A$) then both are evectors. If one of the rows was non-zero in $[A - \lambda_1I]$, the opposite row will be non-zero in $[A - \lambda_2 I]$ and yield the opposite evector. This handles case 3.

If $c \neq 0$ then since
\begin{align}
      [A - \lambda I]
      \left[
      \begin{array}{c}
      \lambda - d \\
      c             \\
      \end{array}
      \right]
&=    \left[
      \begin{array}{c}
      (a-\lambda)(\lambda-d) + bc \\
      c(\lambda-d) + (d-\lambda)c \\ 
      \end{array}
      \right] \\
&=    \left[
      \begin{array}{c}
      (a-\lambda)(\lambda-d) + bc \\
      0 \\ 
      \end{array}
      \right],
\end{align}
case 1 can be verified by showing that 
$(a-\lambda_+)(\lambda_+-d) + bc = (a-\lambda_-)(\lambda_--d) + bc=0$ when $c\neq 0$. Dealing with $\lambda_+$ you find
\begin{align}
   (a-\lambda_+)(\lambda_+-d) + bc
&= \frac{1}{4}(a-d - \sqrt{(a-d)^2 + 4bc})(a-d + \sqrt{(a-d)^2 + 4bc}) + bc \\
&= \frac{1}{4}((a-d)^2 - (a-d)^2 - 4bc) + bc \\
&= 0.
\end{align}
The computation for $\lambda_-$ is almost identical. So this handles case 1, and case 2 is similar.

I hope that clears everything up!

Comment: Please enlighten me if you mind my ancillary edit, to avoid confusion. You correctly pinpointed my algebraic error which I've now have emended in my OP.